# MySql, limint number of articles in each category

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create simple news site, and on home page I want to display all categories, and limit number of article in each category to 5. This is what I got so far.

table categories

```
id    name    
========================================
1    World
2    Sports
3    Economy
4    Music
```

table artices

```
id   category_id  name  
===============================
1    1            Article 1
2    1            Article 2
3    1            Article 3
4    2            Article 11
5    2            Article 22
6    3            Article 33
7    4            Article 111
8    3            Article 222
9    3            Article 333
```

and my query:

```
SELECT
  a.category_id,
  c.name as catname,
  a.name as artname
FROM
  categories AS c
  LEFT JOIN articles AS a
    ON a.category_id = c.id
LIMIT 5;
```

The problem is that limit is applied to categories table, but I actually need to apply to articles table.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "The problem is that limit is applied to categories table, but I actually need to apply to articles table." no limit is applied to a result set not anny tables

Comment: you need to use MySQL's user variables to generate a row_number and filter on that row_number..Search on stackoverflow on `simulate row_number mysql` or `ranking mysql` you should find some examples

Answer (score 0):

If you have a newer MySQL Version with Window functions you can use a Query like this:
You only must specify the fields you want to see

```
SELECT c.*,a.*
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY id DESC ) AS rnr
        FROM articles ) a 
    ON c.id = a.category_id
WHERE rnr < 4
ORDER BY c.id, rnr;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> select * from articles;
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | category_id | name        |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 | Article 1   |
|  2 |           1 | Article 2   |
|  3 |           1 | Article 3   |
|  4 |           2 | Article 11  |
|  5 |           2 | Article 22  |
|  6 |           3 | Article 33  |
|  7 |           4 | Article 111 |
|  8 |           3 | Article 222 |
|  9 |           3 | Article 333 |
+----+-------------+-------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT c.*,a.*
    -> FROM categories c
    -> LEFT JOIN (
    ->     SELECT
    ->         *,
    ->         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY id DESC ) AS rnr
    ->         FROM articles ) a
    ->     ON c.id = a.category_id
    -> WHERE rnr < 4
    -> ORDER BY c.id, rnr;
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------------+------+
| id | name    | id   | category_id | name        | rnr  |
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------------+------+
|  1 | World   |    3 |           1 | Article 3   |    1 |
|  1 | World   |    2 |           1 | Article 2   |    2 |
|  1 | World   |    1 |           1 | Article 1   |    3 |
|  2 | Sports  |    5 |           2 | Article 22  |    1 |
|  2 | Sports  |    4 |           2 | Article 11  |    2 |
|  3 | Economy |    9 |           3 | Article 333 |    1 |
|  3 | Economy |    8 |           3 | Article 222 |    2 |
|  3 | Economy |    6 |           3 | Article 33  |    3 |
|  4 | Music   |    7 |           4 | Article 111 |    1 |
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------------+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```